Attic Moisture/Leaks onto ceiling
I've had slight moisture issues ever since the new roof was installed a couple of years ago.  The ceiling in the bathroom was just painted and there's a water spot again.  I have no idea what the problem is. The roof installers have been out 3 times and say its not a roof issue.  When they installed the roof they had to take 4 feet from each side of the ridge cap vent and close due to new code.  So they put in a new vent to combat that.  Still have issues
I had second roofing company come out and inspect and he agreed that it wasn't a roof leak.  They also inspected the shingles and said everything was good.
They both point out and say AC issues.  I had it pressure tested and they said it was fine.  That was a while ago now but after the new roof was installed.  Maybe we can check that again.
It's admittedly not a lot of water, but any is too much.
My theory is the old fiber glass fiber board (fire prevention) that is cracking/decayed is holding moisture from normal humidity and then releasing it when it rains.  However, that has been in there since the roof was installed and did not have an issue previously.  I don't know how someone could remove it all as its quite tight in places.
Someone throughout this ordeal mentioned maybe installing a vapor barrier....might also have an issue installing it depending how where it goes, I don't really know.
There is no mold from what I can see and the issues is sporadic.  I've been in the attic while is raining and see no obvious issues.
Any idea what type of tradesmen who I could call to help ID and fix the problem? I'm in Florida




You have a ridge vent(good).  Do you also have soffit/bottom vents(not blocked/can see air/light) to move the air?  Vapour barrier is placed behind/above drywall/wall covering and before insulation(depends on local conditions, this is for cold regions).  Any moisture producing stuff, AC units, cold water pipes(condensation)?

The soffit is not blocked.
I don't see any pipes or condensation anywhere.  Theres nothing above the main spot where I get most of my drops.  Just the rafters and plywood....I've scraped off all the old fiberglass stuff in that area as well

Water stains are harder to hide.  Usually need special primers to cover or the stains will bleed though paint.  Usually  primers with kill stains in/on the label, need to be used.  Regular primers/paint and the stain will bleed though.  Maybe making you think the stain is a returning leak.

Thank you for taking the time to answer me.  I don't think thats it, but maybe   I'll check with the painter.
I've put new paper down on top of the insulation in the attic to track new moisture issues and I have new spots there.

Quite a few questions on here about AC drain pipes becoming blocked and causing problems/leaks.  Water does like to travel till it drops.  So depends where it happens can be a lot farther from the spot than you expect.  Have a steel roof with a leak.  I have cover almost every possible leak point above the leak.  Just found out the leak is maybe coming from ten to fifteen feet away.  Side ways at that(not up/down).  Wasted a few quarts of roof tar.  No attic to check either.

Got any pics of the stains and the attic above?
